# Magento 2.3.4: How to reverse admin configuration settings

Tags: magento2.3, php, admin, backend

In the Magento admin, I had to remove `{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{varfax}}{{/depend}}` from all the text boxes under `Address Templates` under `Store->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration` to remove the `fax` field from the checkout page. This removed the fax field, but resulted in `Place Order` button doing nothing during a test order I was trying to place after removing the fax field. I just need to reverse the Admin settings to bring site back to the previous state. Any help is greatly appreciated. Screenshot attached shows where I initially edited but later switched back to Use System Value which now doesn't take any effect now[image].

Comment: check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-import.html

Comment: did you try to change those changes forcefully? I mean by removing disabled something else? Also, is it updating in database?

Comment: I only deleted the line `{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{varfax}}{{/depend}}` nothing else did I touch. I am doing this on the staging server not on the production

Comment: Okay, check `base_url` is in env.php under app/etc directory.

Comment: no, app/etc/env.php doesn't have any entry for `base_url `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only bring back the fax field by setting `isVisible` field of customer_eav_attribute table to 1 after finding out the attribute id for the fax in 'eav_attribute' table, and by running the full build after making these DB changes.